# how to access input value in an array object using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I want to create a function to save data among the `<input>` tag on my HTML page below.

When there is only one `.awardBlock`, I use function `saveData_0()` and it works fine.

But when I add my list `.awardBlock` to more than one and use function `saveData_1()`, it does not work -- the value of `award_class` seem not able to be accessed. the result shows `undefined` when I try to access it using Jquery.

It bothers me and I have debugged for whole afternoon but still no result come out. Thank you for sharing your time, hope I can solve my problem here.

```js
function saveData_0() {
 var prize = {
  name : $('.awardBlock').find('input[name=award_class]').val(),
  content : "cash"
 }
 alert("prize name: " + prize.name);
 alert("prize content: "  + prize.content);
}

function saveData_1() { // when more than one "awardBlock", use this function
 var prize = new Array();
 var numberOfBlock = $('.awardBlock').length;
 
 for(var i=0; i < numberOfBlock ; i++) {
  prize[i] = {
   name : $('.awardBlock:eq(i)').find('input[name=award_class]').val(),
   content : "cash"
  }
 }
 alert("prize name: " + prize[0] +', ' +prize[0].name);
 alert("prize content: " + prize[0] +', ' +prize[0].content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul display-style:none>
 <li class="awardBlock" display-style: none>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="text" name="award_class" placeholder="一等奖"/></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="awardBlock" display-style: none>
  <ul>
   <li><input type="text" name="award_class" placeholder="二等奖"/></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <!-- there maybe more than one "awardBlock" -->
 <li><input type="submit" value="save"  onclick="saveData_1();"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is only one submit button for all of them, you can just make a function that works for all of `awardBlock`s:

```
    function saveData() {
    $('.awardBlock').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
    var prize = {
            name : $this.find('input[name=award_class]').val(),
            content : "cash"
        }
        alert("prize name: " + prize.name);
        alert("prize content: "  + prize.content);
    });

}
```